# Tracert not working on home network

Tags: cmd.exe

I used the tracert command on my computer to connect to another computer on my network and the ip it gave me was this,

fe81::111e:74f9:c9e3:f35b

I have no clue what it is and I'm just curious why I'm not getting my ip adress thanks!

Comment: That *is* an IP address - an IPv6 address.  You are going to need to [edit] this question and add more information before we can help.

Comment: Don't bother using TraceRt for this.  The way TraceRt works is to use TLL to figure out what the last router was that successfully returned a packet, before the first router that failed to return a packet.  That can pinpoint a problem to a specific network(/subnet) if your packet goes through multiple routers on different (sub)nets.  If you're trying to reach something on the same (sub)network, then you won't benefit from any useful new knowledge by using TraceRt to identify which (sub)network has the problem.  (All you'll be left with is confirming what you really already knew to start with.)

Comment: If you want tracert to use IPv4 use the switch -4

Answer (score 1):

That address is an IPv6 address. it is a 128bit address expressed in hexadecimal broken into 2Byte chunks.

On modern windows, if the host has IPv6 enabled, you may need to specify the version of IP to use.

for [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), use:

```
tracert -4 target_host_address
```

this will provide the standard dotted-decimal expression for IPv4 addresses (eg 192.168.0.3).

if you want to use [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), run:

```
tracert -6 target_host_address
```

Here is the usage for tracert on windows10:

```
C:\Windows\system32> tracert /?

Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
    -j host-list       Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
    -R                 Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr         Source address to use (IPv6-only).
    -4                 Force using IPv4.
    -6                 Force using IPv6.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: While technically correct and answering the question which was asked, this answer seems to overlook that the poster's likely goal is unlikely to be achieved by what the poster is trying to do.  The poster seemed to not be t familiar enough with IP networking to identify an IPv6 address.  Given that, it is unlikely that poster has set up a multi-subnet network.  (Maybe multiple subnets may be likely if virtualization is used.  However, that wasn't mentioned, and if multiple subnets were being used, then an fe81::/16 wouldn't be expected for that multi-subnet communication.)